# How to import properties in a class from a list of property names?

Tags: python, properties, python-import

I would like to automate the creation of class properties,
and thus have to write my property imports a way, that allows the code to be changed by a script. I suppose the only reasonable way to achieve that is with a list of property names in a separate file.

Currently my classes look basically like this:

```py
class Foo:

    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar
    
    from classes.foo.properties import spam, eggs
```

I can now replace the line with imports by this horrible thing, and it will work:

```py
    _property_names = ['spam', 'eggs']
    
    for name in _property_names:
        exec(f'from classes.foo.properties import {name}')
```

I tried to use `importlib.import_module` and similar tools, but that did not work.

Is there a reasonable way to do that in a for loop?

Or could I have all the property imports in their own file, and include that in the init file of my class?
(I am not optimistic about that, because importing `*` is allowed only at module level.)

Again, the aim is that a script can change, which modules are imported.
I don't want my script to write around in my class init file.
But appending separate files would be fine.

I hope this question is not too weird. But creating and deleting properties is tedious,
so automating it seems like the right thing to do.
Or is it somehow a bad idea, that a Python program should create and change Python files?

Comment: Do you really need propery objects, or could you implement what you want with `__getattr__` and `__setattr__`?

Comment: I use properties for things that are expensive to calculate, and are not always needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution that works well for me.
It is not what one would expect from the title of the question.
(Which would be the use of something like importlib in a for loop.)

It is what I mentioned as an alternative:

> Or could I have all the property imports in their own file,
> and include that in the init file of my class?

This can indeed be done, by putting all the property imports in the class `FooProperties`,
which is then used as a parent of `Foo`.

This is the folder structure:

- `foo` folder

  - `__init__.py` with class `Foo`
  - `properties` folder

    - `__init__.py` with class `FooProperties`
    - `eggs.py`
    - `spam.py`

The property imports are not in the class definition of *Foo*:

```py
from classes.foo.properties import FooProperties


class Foo(FooProperties):

    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar
```

Instead they are in the class definition of *FooProperties*,
which contains nothing else:

```py
class FooProperties:

    from .spam import spam
    from .eggs import eggs
```

Here is an example of a property:

```py
from functools import cached_property


@cached_property
def eggs(self):
    return f'eggs {self.bar} eggs'
```

A more fleshed out example can be seen on GitHub:
The example class is [*Cat*](https://github.com/entenschule/zoo2/tree/main/proj/classes/animals/cat).
There are also [scripts](https://github.com/entenschule/zoo2/tree/main/proj/scripts/prop) to create and delete properties.
They will re-render the file with the imports, based on a list of names. (The whole reason to have the imports in a separate file, was to make this possible.)

Answer (score 1):

If the goal is to modularly import the properties from a separate file, you can do so using importlib; though I believe flakes' suggestion of using MixIns could provide a more practical alternative depending on your use case.

**foo.py:**

```py
import importlib

class Foo:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._load_properties(["eggs", "ham"])
    
    def _load_properties(self, property_names: list) -> None:
        properties_module = importlib.import_module("properties")
        for name in property_names:
            property = getattr(properties_module, name)
            self.__setattr__(name, property)

thing = Foo()
print(vars(thing))
```

**properties.py:**

```py
eggs = "egg property"
ham = "ham property"
```

The output is `{'eggs': 'egg property', 'ham': 'ham property'}` and the properties are accessible as attributes of the Foo object.

---

This can be modified to import the properties from their own individual modules, if that's your intention, as follows:

**foo.py:**

```py
import importlib

class Foo:
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self._load_properties(["eggs", "ham"])
    
    def _load_properties(self, property_names: list) -> None:
        for name in property_names:
            property_module = importlib.import_module(f"properties.{name}")
            self.__setattr__(name, property_module.get_property())

thing = Foo()
print(thing.eggs)
print(thing.ham)
```

**properties/eggs.py**

```py
class EggsObject:
    pass

def get_property() -> EggsObject:
    return EggsObject()
```

**properties/ham.py**

```py
def get_property() -> str:
    return "ham property"
```

Which will give an output similar to:

```
>>> py foo.py
<properties.eggs.EggsObject object at 0x0000000000000000>``
ham property
```

Comment: This does indeed work for placeholder properties, but I don't get it to work with an actual `@property` that uses setter and getter. [This related question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/286675) shows an example. I can return that in a `get_property`. But then the property of my class instance will just look like `<property object at 0x7ff60d4a96d0>`.

Comment: Same for a `@cached_property` (without setter and getter).

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to easily add properties to a class definition, a much easier way would be to use a mixin.

```
class SpamMixin:
    @property
    def spam(self):
        return "spam: " + self.bar

class EggsMixin:
    @property
    def eggs(self):
        return "eggs: " + self.bar

class Foo(SpamMixin, EggsMixin):
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar

foo = Foo("foo")
print(foo.spam)
print(foo.eggs)
```

```
spam: foo
eggs: foo
```

If you want this to be even more dynamic, you could leave the mixins off the baseclass, but add them to temporary objects as required:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar

class SpamFoo(Foo, SpamMixin): pass
class EggsFoo(Foo, EggsMixin): pass

print(SpamFoo("foo").spam)
print(EggsFoo("foo").eggs)
```

If you still want this more dynamic than that, you could create a factory function, but this would result in loss of type information for static analysis tooling:

```
def create_foo_class(*mixins):
    class Foo(*mixins):
        def __init__(self, bar):
            self.bar = bar
    return Foo


foo = create_foo_class(SpamMixin, EggsMixin)("foo")
print(foo.spam)
print(foo.eggs)
```